# How to withSum on relationship records that have been filtered?

Tags: php, laravel

My $user has relationship called 'earnings', which are basically transactions he earned from. Earnings need to be filtered according to some properties, but when I add withSum, it sums ALL of the relationship records. That's why I had to repeat the filtering subquery when getting 'earnings' and when getting 'earnings_sum_amount'.

Here is the code:

```
$users->with([
            'earnings' => function($query) use ($dateSpanArray, $brandModel) {

                /* Subquery is executing when one of 2 parameters are true */
                $query->when(($dateSpanArray || $brandModel) , function($query) use ($dateSpanArray, $brandModel) {

                    if($brandModel)
                    {
                        $query->whereIn('sender_id', $brandModel->wallets->pluck('id')->toArray());
                    }
                    if($dateSpanArray)
                    {
                        $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$dateSpanArray['from'],$dateSpanArray['to']]);
                    }
                })
                ->latest();
            }]
        )

->withSum([
            'earnings' => function($query) use ($dateSpanArray, $brandModel) {

                $query->when(($dateSpanArray || $brandModel) , function($query) use ($dateSpanArray, $brandModel) {

                    if($brandModel)
                    {
                        $query->whereIn('sender_id', $brandModel->wallets->pluck('id')->toArray());
                    }
                    if($dateSpanArray)
                    {
                        $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$dateSpanArray['from'],$dateSpanArray['to']]);
                    }
                })->select(DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(amount), 0)'));
            }
        ], 'amount')
->get();
```

I was just wondering if there is a better way to write this, to avoid the code repetition?

Comment: why don't you add the repeated part to a separate function or method, and pass the query and other parameters to it, so it will be centralised

Comment: Yeah I could do that too.